# NASM .bss variable error "Access violation writing location 0x000000000000000C."

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, shellcode

I'm very much a newbie on assembly and NASM. I'm trying to define a variable in the .bss section and use it but I couldn't get it to run. It gives me this error:

> "Access violation writing location 0x000000000000000C"

Here is my code:

```
section .bss
    var: resb 64
    
section .text
    global _start
    
_start:
    [BITS 64]
    mov qword [var],10
```

I tried all kind of things like `mov rax, 10` and `mov [var], rax` and this kind of stuff but I couldn't get it to run.

Comment: Why do you have a `bits 64` directive in there?  This should normally not be needed and is a sign that you are doing something terribly wrong.  Please show how you assemble and link your code.

Comment: It wouldn't work without it I'm trying to run it as shellcode. ./nasm -f bin -O3 -o new_3.bin new_3.asm

Comment: if it doesn't work without the directive you are doing something wrong.  Please post the exact commands you type to assemble and link your code.

Comment: ./nasm -f bin -O3 -o new_3.bin new_3.asm

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: int main()
{
 ((FARPROC)buf)();
}


I pass it as bytecode and run it

Comment: Yeah ok, that won't work.  Let me write an answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do will not work.

This is because when writing shell code, there is no other section than the text section.  It is not possible to define static variables and read/write them.  You additionally run into the problem that shell code must be position independent, but nasm defaults to an absolute addressing mode for

```
[var]
```

To fix this, you need to write

```
[rel var]
```

choosing a rip-relative addressing mode or select such an addressing mode by default by issueing

```
default rel
```

Neverthless, there will not be a bss section at run time, so writing to a variable in it will not work.  Instead, you could for example place variables on the stack like such:

```
sub rsp, 8
mov qword [rsp], 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried something Like that I tried [rbp-8] for example it woks but it is not stable it seems that stack may change the values on it's will later on in programm

Comment: @jeffrey Unless you have set up `rbp` to point to a reasonable place, it'll just have an unknown value.  You cannot expect that value to point to memory available for you to use.

Comment: `-b` is an ndisasm option, not nasm. At least my recent NASM build doesn't recognise it. This is a rare case in which using a `bits` directive in the source is actually the right way.

Comment: @ecm Interesting!  Seems like I misremembered this.